# Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm - .net Core

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, .net-core

I am  getting the following error message when I convert from .net 4.5 to .net core 2.  The code is exactly the same. I have seen a few posts but none have solve this error. I am using RijndaelManaged encryption.

```
 Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.

  at Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoDecryptor.DepadBlock(Byte[] block, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoDecryptor.UncheckedTransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextReader.Dispose()
```

Below is the code that I am using.  I am getting the error at: 
**retval = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();**

```
 public static class EncryptionExtension
{

    #region "Enumerations"

    public enum EncryptionAlgorithms
    {

        Rijndael = 0

    }


    public enum CryptMethod
    {
        Encrypt = 0,
        Decrypt = 1
    }

    #endregion

    #region "Private Attributes"

    private static byte[] CRYPT_SALT = {
        99,
        115,
        120,
        76,
        105,
        103,
        105,
        116
    };
    private static byte[] IV_8 = new byte[] {
        2,
        63,
        9,
        36,
        235,
        174,
        78,
        12
    };
    private static byte[] IV_16 = new byte[] {
        15,
        199,
        56,
        77,
        244,
        126,
        107,
        239,
        9,
        10,
        88,
        72,
        24,
        202,
        31,
        108
    };
    private static byte[] IV_24 = new byte[] {
        37,
        28,
        19,
        44,
        25,
        170,
        122,
        25,
        25,
        57,
        127,
        5,
        22,
        1,
        66,
        65,
        14,
        155,
        224,
        64,
        9,
        77,
        18,
        251
    };
    private static byte[] IV_32 = new byte[] {
        133,
        206,
        56,
        64,
        110,
        158,
        132,
        22,
        99,
        190,
        35,
        129,
        101,
        49,
        204,
        248,
        251,
        243,
        13,
        194,
        160,
        195,
        89,
        152,
        149,
        227,
        245,
        5,
        218,
        86,
        161,
        124
        #endregion
    };

    #region "String Encryption"

    public static string EncryptString(EncryptionAlgorithms Method, string Value, string Key)
    {
        return CryptString(CryptMethod.Encrypt, Method, Value, Key);
    }

    public static string DecryptString(EncryptionAlgorithms Method, string Value,  string Key)
    {
        return CryptString(CryptMethod.Decrypt, Method, Value, Key);
    }

    public static string CryptString(CryptMethod Method, EncryptionAlgorithms Algorithm, string Value, string Key)
    {
        // Check arguments.    
        if (Value == null || Value.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Data can not be empty");
        }
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key can not be empty");
        }

        SymmetricAlgorithm provider = null;
        string retval = null;

        // Declare the stream used to encrypt to an in memory array of bytes.    
        MemoryStream msCrypt = null;
        ICryptoTransform ICrypt = null;

        try
        {
            // Create a Provider object    
            switch (Algorithm)
            {
                case EncryptionAlgorithms.Rijndael:
                    provider = new RijndaelManaged();
                    break;
            }

            provider.KeySize = provider.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
            provider.BlockSize = provider.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;

            provider.Key = DerivePassword(Key, provider.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize / 8);

            switch (provider.BlockSize / 8)
            {
                case 8:
                    provider.IV = IV_8;
                    break;
                case 16:
                    provider.IV = IV_16;
                    break;
                case 24:
                    provider.IV = IV_24;
                    break;
                case 32:
                    provider.IV = IV_32;
                    break;
            }

            if (Method == CryptMethod.Encrypt)
            {
                ////encrypt value    

                //// Create a encryptor to perform the stream transform.    
                //ICrypt = provider.CreateEncryptor(provider.Key, provider.IV);

                //// Create the streams used for encryption/decryption    
                //msCrypt = new MemoryStream();

                //using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msCrypt, ICrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                //{
                //    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                //    {
                //        //Write all data to the stream.    
                //        swEncrypt.Write(Value);
                //    }
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                //decrypt value    

                //convert the ciphered text into a byte array    
                byte[] cipherBytes = null;
                cipherBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Value);

                // Create a deccryptor to perform the stream transform.    
                ICrypt = provider.CreateDecryptor(provider.Key, provider.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.    
                msCrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes);

                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msCrypt, ICrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {


                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        //Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                          retval = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //throw new AceExplorerException(ex.Message + "  " + ex.StackTrace + " " + ex.TargetSite.ToString() + " " + ex.Source, ex.InnerException);
              throw new Exception(ex.Message + "  " + ex.StackTrace + " " + ex.TargetSite.ToString() + " " + ex.Source, ex.InnerException);

        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the Provider object.    
            if ((provider != null))
            {
                provider.Clear();
            }
        }

        if (Method == CryptMethod.Encrypt)
        {
            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.    
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(msCrypt.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            // Return the unencrypted text    
            return retval;
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region "Private Utility Functions"

    private static byte[] DerivePassword(string Password, int Length)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password, CRYPT_SALT, 5);
        return derivedBytes.GetBytes(Length);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The to run it you can do the following

```
var decryptedstring = EncryptionExtension.CryptString(EncryptionExtension.CryptMethod.Decrypt, EncryptionExtension.EncryptionAlgorithms.Rijndael, "[Encrypted String]", "[key]");
```

**Update:**
I have added the full class. Sorry I didnt see the blocked out sections

**Update 2:**
I changed the PaddingMode to None.  I no longer see the error.  But now the return value is: �s)���j�U�#V�İ��H?X�

**Update 3:**
When debugging the code on 4.5 I have:
 - Padding in PKCS7
 - BlockSize = 256 vs 128 in Core
I tried Jimi's code but got strange characters: 寛Щ�챫蔧⽢쉈⩭｣啌斪ᆈ锚ય杄䕳
I tried modifying it by using the following: Convert.ToBase64String(DecodedText);
I didn't have the strange characters but not the results I was expecting.

**Expected Results:**

**Key:** DNACTSACEENGINE

**string:** IdIFR+PP5yDggqgSlB0KfcNTG+DkRuRbPfeljJeGm+c=

**results:** !vbqZgZKbu4?8

**Update**
.Net Core doesnt support a blocksize of 256

Thanks in advance.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: So what actually happens? The exact same code works on .NET but not .NET Core? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I think the first thing to change is `provider.Key = DerivePassword(...);`. Change it into `PasswordDeriveBytes secret = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Key, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((provider.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize / 8).ToString()));`. The `StreamReader` is useless here, unless you use an `Encoding` (Unicode, possibly), anyway, the same used by the encryption. I'ld get the `csDecrypt` stream, transform it in `byte[]`, then use `Encoding.Unicode.GetString()` for the final conversion. I don't know how the `switch (provider.BlockSize / 8)` would work.

Comment: What is the padding mode? Your code does not set it.

Comment: On a side note, IV's should be random.

Comment: @glenebob   tried setting the adding mode but no luck

Comment: @Jimi  Thanks.  For the DerivePassword I posted the full code.  How would I stream the csDecrypt to a string?

Comment: But, why is the encryption method commented out? What are you decrypting here?

Comment: Anyway, see if these modifications can fix the issue. The code I posted supposes that what is presented in the Encryption commented out method is consistent with the result you are expecting from the Decryption method (the value to Decrypt is produced by an Ecryption method compatible with the one shown in your code).

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed the part that did not produce a consistent result.

But, since the Encryption method is commented out in your code, I'm not sure whether the Encrypted input value is exactly what is presented here or it comes from a different source and/or a different method of Encryption.

I've integrated the `MemoryStream` assigned byte array, used by both the Encryption and the Decryption methods, with the `Unicode` Encoding/Decoding of the original value.
Of course another Encoding can be used. (Tested also with `UTF8`, which should be the default).
The string is Base64Encoded/Decoded as usual.

I'm posting here just the section of code included in the `#region "String Encryption"` block.
The rest of the code is untouched.

`Tested on: Visual Studio pro 15.8.0`
`.Net FrameWork: Core 2.1`
`C# 6.0 and C# 7.3`

The Ecryption/Decryption methods are called this way:

```
string encryptedstring = EncryptionExtension.CryptString(
        EncryptionExtension.CryptMethod.Encrypt, EncryptionExtension.EncryptionAlgorithms.Rijndael, 
            "Some text to encrypt, more text to encrypt", "SomeKey");
string decryptedstring = EncryptionExtension.CryptString(
        EncryptionExtension.CryptMethod.Decrypt, EncryptionExtension.EncryptionAlgorithms.Rijndael, 
            encryptedstring, "SomeKey");
```

---

```
#region "String Encryption"

public static string EncryptString(EncryptionAlgorithms Method, string Value, string Key)
{
    return CryptString(CryptMethod.Encrypt, Method, Value, Key);
}

public static string DecryptString(EncryptionAlgorithms Method, string Value, string Key)
{
    return CryptString(CryptMethod.Decrypt, Method, Value, Key);
}
```

---

```
public static string CryptString(CryptMethod Method, EncryptionAlgorithms Algorithm, string Value, string Key)
{
    if (Value == null || Value.Length <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Data can not be empty");
    }
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key can not be empty");
    }

    SymmetricAlgorithm provider = null;

    try
    {
        switch (Algorithm)
        {
            case EncryptionAlgorithms.Rijndael:
                provider = new RijndaelManaged();
                break;
        }
        provider.KeySize = provider.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
        provider.BlockSize = provider.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
        provider.Key = DerivePassword(Key, provider.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize / 8);

        switch (provider.BlockSize / 8)
        {
            case 8:
                provider.IV = IV_8;
                break;
            case 16:
                provider.IV = IV_16;
                break;
            case 24:
                provider.IV = IV_24;
                break;
            case 32:
                provider.IV = IV_32;
                break;
        }

        if (Method == CryptMethod.Encrypt)
        {
            byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Value);

            // Create the streams used for encryption/decryption    
            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = provider.CreateEncryptor(provider.Key, provider.IV))
            using (var msCrypt = new MemoryStream())
            using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msCrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                csEncrypt.Write(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(msCrypt.ToArray());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Value);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.    
            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = provider.CreateDecryptor(provider.Key, provider.IV))
            using (var msCrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes))
            using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msCrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                byte[] decodedText = new byte[cipherBytes.Length];
                int decryptedCount = csDecrypt.Read(decodedText, 0, decodedText.Length);
                return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decodedText, 0, decryptedCount);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //throw new AceExplorerException(ex.Message + "  " + ex.StackTrace + " " + ex.TargetSite.ToString() + " " + ex.Source, ex.InnerException);
        throw new Exception(ex.Message + "  " + ex.StackTrace + " " + ex.TargetSite.ToString() + " " + ex.Source, ex.InnerException);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clear the Provider object.    
        provider?.Clear();
    }
}
#endregion

private static byte[] DerivePassword(string password, int length)
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, CRYPT_SALT, 1000);
    return derivedBytes.GetBytes(length);
}
```

Comment: Didnt work for me. I got the strange characters as mentioned above.  Also, I added provider.Padding = PaddingMode.None; to get rid of the 1st error

Comment: @H20rider   As I said before, it depends on the input string. If you encode a string with the encryption method here, the string is decrypted correctly. You need to specify where the string you're trying to decrypt comes from. And how it is encoded. Did you test this code with the sample methods above? And did you substitute all your current code block with the one posted here?

Comment: I did.  This is the expected results. 
Key: DNACTSACEENGINE
String: IdIFR+PP5yDggqgSlB0KfcNTG+DkRuRbPfeljJeGm+c=
Return: !vbqZgZKbu4?8
When I ran the above, I get the padding error.  When I change the padding, then it returns a value in strange text
Also the encrypt just needs to be uncommented

Comment: That string has an invalid padding! What are you using to encrypt it? Not the encryption method I modified here. So which one? Post the un-encrypted string. And to test it, use the encryption method I posted. also, you need to **change the whole code modified**. You can't copy/paste just one part. All the code from `#region "String Encryption"` to the end.

Comment: I copied the code exactly.  Did you try using the values i used

Comment: What  values? Do you mean the bunch of characters pasted on a Web Page? You need to use this code for both Encryption and Decryption. If you want to make a test, encrypt a string and see whether it is decrypted correctly. You can't decrypt a random string without knowing how it was encoded. I'm not referring to the Base64 encoding, but to the CodePage of the original characters. You, still, haven't said how that string you are showing was **Encrypted**. Or, at least, what was it's original **Encoding**. (Note the emphasis on the 2 different terms).

Comment: I posted the Key, value and the encrypted values above. I encrypt it using the encrypted code above that was commented out
                var text = EncryptionExtension.CryptString(EncryptionExtension.CryptMethod.Decrypt, EncryptionExtension.EncryptionAlgorithms.Rijndael,  @"IdIFR+PP5yDggqgSlB0KfcNTG+DkRuRbPfeljJeGm+c=", "DNACTSACEENGINE");

Comment: You can't do that. You have to encrypt/decrypt the original (plain text) string with the code I posted here. In your comment, you're trying to **decrypt** a Base64 encoded string. If you have, let's say, a codebase of encrypted string you need to decrypt, you have to say what parameters were used. Otherwise the decryption won't work. Did you change the Padding mode in `switch (Algorithm)`, adding `provider.Padding = [Some Padding Mode]`? (Note that PKCS7 is the default, if no padding was specified). The encrypted string was created with these parameters?

Comment: Also, if you did't use an Encoding in your original methods, change the Encoding in the code I posted to from `Unicode` to `UTF8`. Don't use a mix of methods: or you are using the encryption/decryption I posted, or you use yours. See if using mine while encryting and then decripting `!vbqZgZKbu4?8` with any padding, you have consistent results.