# How to convert ReDim?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to translate vb code to C# with code ReDim problem. I use convertor online but can't work for this case.   Someone know to to translate it.

```
        Private bytIV() As Byte = _
        {12, 241, 10, 21, 90, 74, 11, 39, 9, 91, 45, 78, 189, 211, 133, 62, 121, 22, 101, 34, 90, 74, 121, 39, 93, 9, 45, 78, 1, 211, 33, 162}

       If (_CryptoService.LegalBlockSizes.Length > 0) Then
            Dim maxSize As Integer = _CryptoService.LegalBlockSizes(0).MaxSize
            ReDim Preserve bytIV(sTemp.Length - 1)
            If sTemp.Length * 8 > maxSize Then
                ReDim Preserve bytIV(maxSize / 8 - 1)
            End If
        End If
```

What does bytIV() exactly use for in Encrypt job?

## how to translate ReDim in Csharp?

Much thanks.

Comment: `bytIV` is the initialisation vector. That's too general a subject to discuss on SO but you can search for those keywords to find out the point.

Comment: See [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888378/7444103) (`RijndaelManaged`, but adaptable).

Comment: Array.Resize(ref YourArray, i + 1);

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney, I got your advice because I very young in  byte code. Howevery much thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing available in C# is `Array.Resize`, which is standard .NET and thus available in VB too.  You might like to try using it in the VB code to see whether you get the same result first, then the translation to C# will be easier.

In your code, these lines:

```vb
ReDim Preserve bytIV(sTemp.Length - 1)
ReDim Preserve bytIV(maxSize / 8 - 1)
```

would become this:

```vb
Array.Resize(bytIV, sTemp.Length)
Array.Resize(bytIV, maxSize / 8)
```

Note that `Array.Resize` takes a new length rather than a new upper bound.  Converting those lines to C# would consist of appending a semicolon.

I should also point out that, with `Option Strict On` (as it should pretty much always be), that VB code would have to use integer division:

```vb
ReDim Preserve bytIV(maxSize \ 8 - 1)
Array.Resize(bytIV, maxSize \ 8)
```

In C#, integer division is automatic when dividing one `int` by another, so the operator looks the same as regular division.

EDIT: prompted by Mary's comment above, I realised that converting the `Array.Resize` calls from VB to C# would require the addition of the `ref` keyword too, as the first parameter is passed by reference.

```c#
Array.Resize(ref bytIV, sTemp.Length);
Array.Resize(ref bytIV, maxSize / 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me you solution. Thank you  very much.

```
Array.Resize(ref bytIV, sTemp.Length);
Array.Resize(ref bytIV, maxSize / 8);
```